# QGIS: Add geotagged photos to already existing photos.gpkg file

Tags: qgis-3, photos, geotag

I'm working with QGIS Desktop 3.4.12 Madeira, standalone. Operating System: Windows 10.

Is it possible to add new geotagged images to an already existing „photos.gpkg“ file? If yes, how?

The existing file „photos.gpkg“ was created by the QGIS function „Import geotagged photos“ (finding in the „Toolbox“ at „Vector creation“) and saved as gpkg file.

I already tried to overwrite the old file, but there comes an error saying that it doesn`t work: „OGR-error: A file system object called XYZ already exists.“ (even though the system asked me before if I would like to overwrite the file)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, although not from the "Import geotagged photos" dialog;

1. Save your first layer;
2. Import the second geotagged photos as temporary layer.
3. Then you right-click the second layer and select "Export > Save features as", a dialog will prompt, there you choose the first layer as "File name"
4. When you click "Ok" you'll be prompted to choose "overwrite" or "append", choose append

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. I understand, I need to save the first layer as a shape file, it doesn’t work with gpkg. Just to add: The style disappeared in the newly created file, that’s why I saved the style and loaded it in the new shape file.

Comment: I did it with both gpgks; gpkgs are spatial data bases, they're designed to append data to an existing db